# INTERSECT & EXCEPT [SQL Server 2012]

Tags: sql-server

I have one problem that i can't find nice solution for.

I have relational table `Groups_Members` with columns `GroupId` and `MemberId`.

I have a stored procedure that creates a new group and receives an array of `memberId` as parameter (user defined type). What I want is to make sure that there is not a group with exactly the same members in the database already.

I'm trying to figure out how `EXCEPT` operator might help me but I can't. I need condition that would return the group that has exactly the same set of members as those in my `memberId` parameter (or null or 0 if such group doesn't exist).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Well - INTERSECT and EXCEPT just take one query and compares to another query, and with INTERSECT takes what is the same in both and EXCEPT takes from the first - what is not in the second.

I'm unsure what help you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Members table(id int)
insert into @Members
values(1), (3), (4)

Declare @MemberCount int
Select @MemberCount = count(id) From @Members

--Select GroupId from 
--(Select distinct groupId, memberid from Groups_Members) gm
--Inner Join @Members On MemberId = id
--group by GroupId
--Having COUNT(MemberId) = @MemberCount
```

When values(1), (3), (4) (it works correctly).

But when values(1), (2) (it does not work correctly).

Nice try but it does not provide the exact matching with group members.

Try this for better solution

```
Select Gm.GroupId from 
(Select distinct  GroupId, memberid from Groups_Members) gm
Inner Join @Members On MemberId = id
Inner join (Select COUNT(MemberId) as Totalmember,GroupId 
from Groups_Members group by GroupId) tgm on tgm.GroupId = gm.GroupId
where Totalmember = @MemberCount
group by gm.GroupId
Having COUNT(MemberId) = @MemberCount
```

Description can be provided on demand.

Comment: yes, correct. this solution works. it would be nice to hear a word of explanaion, if possible. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Table Groups_Members

```
GroupId|MemberId
   1   |   1
   1   |   2
   1   |   3
   2   |   1
   2   |   2
   2   |   4
   3   |   1
   3   |   3
   3   |   4
```

```
Declare @Members table(id int)
insert into @Members
values(1), (3), (4)

Declare @MemberCount int
Select @MemberCount = count(id) From @Members

Select GroupId from 
(Select distinct groupId, memberid from Groups_Members) gm
Inner Join @Members On MemberId = id
group by GroupId
Having COUNT(MemberId) = @MemberCount
```

Result would be 3

Description can be provided on demand.

Comment: Yes, please describe a bit if you have time.

Comment: From: A sub query to return all distinct data from Groups_Members table.

Comment: Join: A inner join with the array received, to restrict records to members passed in the array. You can use a sub query instead.

Comment: Group By: Grouped by GroupId to get count of members per group. The count will only include members of the array. A sort of intersection.

Comment: Having: Only group having the no. of member equal to the no. of members in the array will be returned, which means the group having same members will be returned, if not any then nothing will be returned.

Comment: Hi!
First of all, please take my apologies for not responding a few days. I was out of town and couldn't see the solution. I did try the solution but the part with matching number of members seems to be missing one more condition. And that is the one where input set is a subset of existing group. For example, as @Faraz Ahmed pointed out afterwards, if you put any subset as input parameter (for example, (1), (2)) then it returns the gruop (and it shouldn't). Anyways, your answer was really helpful to guide me in right direction so i'll vote it as helpful. Many thanks!